# Jquery Cross Domain Ajax - Windows Universal HTML App

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm creating a universal app for Windows 10 using HTML and Jquery (Visual Studio), Jquery works fine, but I'm trying to scrape html (specific divs) from an external website, using the Jquery plugin: Jquery Cross Domain Ajax : jquery.xdomainajax.js, I made this also in pure html, and ran it into the browser and that worked.

However, when I run it as an application, It doesn't retrieve data...

I have it (jquery.xdomainajax.js) localy included (/js/jquery.xdomainajax.js) under the jquery include  code.

Will this ever be possible?, I tried and tried, but I'm starting to give up on it, my goal was to convert the working html file to a universal app...

(if only that would work, my app would be completed)

But now I'm stuck there.

Anyway thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by ' It doesn't retrieve data.'  ? is it giving you crossdomain error? Would help if you can post the error that you are gettting

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Windows 8 app using JavaScript and WinJS several months ago, and I did some cross domain Ajax to grab some external webpage too. I suppose that you are doing the same thing as I did.

I am not sure that WinJS works fine with jQuery, and I did it in the native way.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
var requestUrl = "website";
xhr.open("get", requestUrl, true);
xhr.send(null);

var jsonText = xhr.responseText;
// ....
```

You may want to check out my data.js code [here](https://github.com/iplus26/Watched/blob/master/Watched/js/data.js). I was a beginner and the code is very dirty.